# Swift executes file that was never called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm quite new to Xcode.

My question is, why does Swift execute GameScene.swift? There is no function which calls GameScene.swift (default-not edited). 
However, when I run the application and click it gives me those coloured squares (from the default code).
This not what I want, or what I expected. Why does this happen, and how do I get around this without deleting the code of GameScene.swift. What am I looking for?

[image: Xcode]

```
        if let scene = Menu(fileNamed: "Menu") {
        // Configure the view.

        scene.propertyListData = "Menu"
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = false
        skView.showsNodeCount = false
        skView.showsPhysics = false
        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about sceneit, but is this file used by your story boards or sks files?

Comment: Yes, both are in use.

Comment: So, there's your answer?

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear from your question, but my guess is that you've left the controller class unchanged in the storyboard:

[image]

As you see, the controller's class (in the right-hand pane) is set to `GameViewController`. This will cause the system to instantiate the `GameViewController` class when the storyboard is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I found it! Each .sks file has a custom class set. In my case, the Custom class was set to GameScene.swift (right side). It's now corrected to 'Menu.swift'.

[image]